# text under input text in appearance of autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, autocomplete

Im trying to do something similar to autocomplete in my site with jquery,
but i dont even know from where to start do that.

It is hard for me to explane (my english is bad),
so i will show you in pictures(A picture is worth a thousand words?).

This is input:
[image]

And after the user is typing a window will Appear like that:
[image]

And when user press on the  **"search 'bla'..."**  it will be same as pressing **'send'**.
Im only need that under the input will be:
**"search" + the value on the input + "..."** - thats it.

Here a try, but it need to be in window like auto complete, not in label.

```js
$('#search').keyup(function() {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
if(inputValue == "")
{ $('#label').text("");}else{
       $('#label').text("search "+inputValue+"...");}
        
    
});
```

```css
#label
{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="search"><input value="send" id="submit" type="submit">
<br>
<label for="submit" id="label"></label>

</form>
```

Im realy hope that you understand!
Thank you and sory about my english ! :)

Comment: but i dont need to use list from database or to autocomplete the word, unly to write:
"search"+the value on the input.  
and that it will use as a button

Comment: Please don't ramble in questions. The first two paragraphs do not add anything to your question. Please start sentences with a Capital and end them with a full stop, unless there is a good reason to not do that.

Comment: Easy @Sumurai8 this isn't an English essay, he's clearly trying to let us know he has trouble with English.

Comment: Can you post some code @anonicode

Comment: @DaveBriand I just gave a few relative simple tips how they could improve their questions. Adding capitals and full stops to a text greatly improves readability, even if other words are misspelled and the order of the words is incorrect. I would have changed it myself, but this question needs to be closed and I don't want to invalidate close-votes.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbin.com/ralugu/1/

Comment: Im realy sorry, my English isnt perfect. i updated my question and add code.
@DaveBriand